# Existence of a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

> To every real $x$ assign a finite set $\mathcal{A}(x)\subset \mathbb{R}$
>   where $x\not\in \mathcal{A}(x)$. Does there exist $\mathcal{W}\subset
>  \mathbb{R}$ such that:
>
> $$1.\;\;\mathcal{W}\cap \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{W})=\varnothing\qquad
>  2.\;\;|\mathcal{W}|=|\mathbb{R}|$$

This interesting problem was given to me by a friend, but I can't do it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think I understand this exactly. The assignment of $A(x)$ is given (and arbitrary) or we may define it? (in the latter case a solution seem trivial)

Comment: Zorn's lemma maybe?

Comment: @AndreaMori Arbitrary.

Comment: @AndreaMori: The assignment is given before "Does there exist" asks a question.

Comment: @Andrea Mori : The assignment of $A(x)$ is arbitrary. If we may define it, it would be easy ; take $A(x) = \{x+1\}$ and $W = [0,1/2]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{Q}=\{[p,q]:\;p,q\in\mathbb{Q},\;p<q\}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ finite $\Rightarrow$ we may choose $\phi:\;\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{Q}:$ $$(\text{i}):\;\;x\in\phi(x)\qquad (\text{ii}):\;\;\phi(x)\cap\mathcal{A}(x)=\varnothing$$
Since $|\mathcal{Q}|=|\mathbb{N}|$ there exists $I\in\mathcal{Q}$ such that $\text{card}\,\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\;\phi(x)=I\}=\mathfrak{c}\;(\Leftarrow$ [König's th.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29)$)$. Let $\mathcal{W}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\;\phi(x)=I\}$ and check $\mathcal{W}\cap\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{W})=\varnothing\;(\Leftarrow\mathcal{W}\subset  I$ and $I\cap \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{W})=\varnothing)$

Comment: Did that argument come naturally for you? Man this is a weird idea. But it seems to work beautifully. +1

Answer (score 2):

The following approach uses not only the Axiom of Choice (in the fomr of Zorn's lemma), but also the OCntinuum Hypothesis - and I am somewhat shocked that I cannot get rid of the latter:

Call $W$ nice if $W\cap \mathcal A(W)=\emptyset$.
The nice subsets are inductively ordered (cf. answer by Patrick da Silva).
For any subset $T\subseteq \mathbb R$ with $T\approx \mathbb R$, define
$$ \begin{align}\mathcal A_T(x)&=\mathcal A(x)\cap T\\
\mathcal B_T(x) &= \mathcal A_T(x)\cup\{\,y\in T\mid x\in\mathcal A_T(y)\,\}\\
S_T&= \{\,x\in T\mid \mathcal B_T(x)\text{ uncountable}\,\}.
\end{align}$$
Clearly, a subset $W$ of $T$ is nice if and only if $W\cap \mathcal A_T(W)=\emptyset$.
Note that $\mathcal B_T(x)$ is the set of elements that are "forbidden" to add to a nice subset of $T$ that already contains $x$, that is if $W$ is nice and $y\notin W$, then $W\cap \{y\}$ is nice iff $y\notin\bigcup_{x\in W}\mathcal B(x)$.

If $S_T\ne T$, Zorn's lemma implies that there exists a maximal nice subset $M_T$ of $T\setminus S_T$.
If $M_T\approx \mathbb R$, we are done.
So assume $|M_T|<|\mathbb R|$. Then $\bigcup_{x\in M_T} \mathcal B_T(x)$ is the  union of $M_T$-many countable sets, hence has cardinality $<|\mathbb R|$. Any element of $T\setminus S_T\setminus M_T$ could be added to $M_T$ without harm, so by maximality $T\setminus S_T\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in M_T} \mathcal B_T(x)$, i.e. $S_T$ differs from $T$ only by a smaller set. So  $S_T\approx T\approx \mathbb R$.

**Result:** We may assume wlog. that $S_T\approx\mathbb R$ for all $T\subseteq \mathbb R$ with $T\approx \mathbb R$.

Now since $$S_{\mathbb R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{\,x\in S_{\mathbb R}\mid n\ge |\mathcal A(x)| \,\},$$
there must exist $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\{\,x\in S_{\mathbb R}\mid n\ge |\mathcal A(x)| \,\}\approx\mathbb R$.
Thus we can let $N\in\mathbb N$ be minimal with the property that there exists $T\subseteq S_{\mathbb R}$ with $T\approx \mathbb R$ and $|\mathcal A_T(x)|\le N$ for all $x\in T$.
By our result, $S_T\approx\mathbb R$. Pick $x\in S_T$ and let $U=\{\,y\in T\mid x\in \mathcal A_T(y)\,\}$. Then $U$ is an uncountable subset of $S_{\mathbb R}$ and $|\mathcal A_U(y)|\le N-1$ for all $y\in U$. By the Continuum Hypothesis, $U\approx \mathbb R$ and we obtain a contradiction to the minimality of $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the "conflict range" of $x$ to be $d(x)=\min\{|x-y| : y\in \cal{A}(x)\}$.  That is, $d(x)$ measures the distance from $x$ to its (finite) set of conflicts; note that $d(x)>0$ for each $x$.  Choose a distance $\Delta>0$ such that there are uncountably many $x$ with $d(x) > \Delta$.  For instance, since$$d^{-1}((1,\infty)) \cup \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}d^{-1}\left((2^{-(k+1)},2^{-k}]\right)= \mathbb{R},$$
at least one of the sets in the union is uncountable, and we can choose $\Delta$ to be the lower endpoint of its argument.  Now let ${\cal{D}}=d^{-1}\left((\Delta,\infty)\right)$, and note that
$$
\bigcup_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{\cal{D}}\cap(k\Delta, (k+1)\Delta]={\cal D}.
$$
Each of the sets ${\cal{D}}\cap(k\Delta,(k+1)\Delta]$ is conflict-free by construction (its diameter is less than any of its elements' conflict ranges), and at least *one* of them must be uncountable (since their union is uncountable). That set satisfies the conditions of the problem. $\square$